# Multiple Doxygen \relatedalso

Tags: doxygen

Let's say we have

```
class A
{ ... };

class B
{ ... };

class C
{ ... };
```

and let's say we have a free-function like

```
C operator*(A, B)
{ .... }
```

Is there a way to make `operator*` to appear in the *related functions* section of all A, B and C ?

I tried `\relatedalso`, but it seem to work only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you place `\relatedalso` - documentation of the class(es) or the operator?

You can insert `\relates` for eacht class at your operators documentation:

```cpp
/** This is class A. */
class A
{
    // ...
};

/** This is class B. */
class B
{
    // ...
};

/** This is class C. */
class C
{
    // ...
};


/**
 * This is an operator.
 * 
 * \relates A
 * \relates B
 * \relates C
 * 
 * @param a     Class A
 * @param b     Class B
 * @return      Something
 */
C operator*(A a, B b)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Doxygen (html):**

```cpp
Related Functions

(Note that these are not member functions.)
C   operator* (A a, B b)
```

*(`operator*` is linked to it's documentation)*

Comment: This is **excactly** what I did (apart `\relates` vs `relatealso` for which I saw no difference). `C   operator* (A a, B b)` appears in the "*related functions*" of C, but not in the same sections of A and B.

Comment: I see ... I thought there's a difference. unfortunately it seems to be an open bug:  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612617

Comment: uh-oh, so I wasn't drunk! It seems I have to wait for a further release! Thank you for finding it!